# How to Read DB Connection String from System Registry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection-string

We are using ASP.NET 3.5 and C# 3.0.

According to the client's requirement, the database connection string need to be stored in system registry.During the connection establishment,we have to read the connection string from System Registry.

How can i store connection string in System Registry?

Using C# how can i programmatically read my connectionString?

Storing connectionString in System's registry is a good practice?

Comment: why the registry? Why don't you use the standard, accepted .NET way of doing things - store connection strings in the web.config file?

Answer (score 2):

Please, read following article: [Read, write and delete from registry with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx)

If it's a good practice? IMHO, I don't think so. Your web application can be hosted in multiple machines, and all them needs to store same key.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is information](http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=264) about how to access the registry from C#.

You can store the connection string in the registry, though that's not a very common practice these days.  Whether it is a good idea depends on the security requirements and on how well locked-down the PC's are where this will run.

Since the inception of .NET, there has been a trend to pull this type of configuration information out of the registry and into configuration files.